# VS2010 constantly searching for something

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Recently my VS has started doing a search through all project assemblies after a project is reloaded, or after I close a window following a Go to Definition command. It just says Searching in the status bar, and enumerates the assembly names. It's driving me nuts, because the process can take up to a minute, and it completely locks up the whole application while it's doing this.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks,

Aleko

Answer (score 0):

I would say all the time. Situation got better after installing SP1 and especially after disabling WPF interface. This can be done through Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Visual Experience. Disable "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" & "Enable rich client visual experience". Enable "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available". Buy a better graphic card. I have read about another user experiences that buying faster graphics card made a noticable improvement of Visual Studio (version 2005).

Comment: It stopped happening by itself a while back. I have no idea why... Visuals Studio seems to have a mind of its own.